# How to Have a Web Server

Tags: php, android, cordova, upload, webserver

I am trying to build a mobile application that allows users to upload photos to a webserver and then lets the users view them on their phone and online.  I am using phonegap and developing for Android and I understand pretty well what to do on the phonegap side but I don't know how to create a webserver.

Are there websites that will host it for me and what kind of coding do I need to do?  I know a decent amount of PHP but I just don't know where to get started.  I want to start off pretty small so say 50 uploads a day or so.

Comment: So... you're cloning Instagram? Flickr? Picasa?

Comment: google is your friend, try searching for [php hosting](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=16&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=best+php+hosting) as well as [how to upload an image in php](http://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=16&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=upload+image+php&pf=p&output=search) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Google's App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) its a great place to get started with something like this. Although it requires you program in Java, Python, or Go rather than php.

If you really want to code in php any web server provider should be sufficient

Comment: my question though is how do I  get a web server?

Comment: Purchase one from a provider. There are literally hundreds of providers: GoDaddy, BlueHost, HostGator are 3 that come to mind. Just do a google search for Web Server Provider

Answer (score 1):

You need:
  1) a php web server with either root access or at least FTP access
  2) backend php code to save uploaded files
  3) Android client code to upload files

This link here:

http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

shows answers to 2) and 3).  Good luck!